# Handling Two Puppet Classes with the Same Name

Tags: elasticsearch, puppet, librarian-puppet

I want to use the [elasticsearch/elasticsearch](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) module in my own module called `rehan`. The elasticsearch/elasticsearch module provides a class called `elasticsearch`. If I also want to create a class in my module that makes use of the one in elasticsearch/elasticsearch, how can I achieve this? I have tried:

```
class rehan::elasticsearch {

    class { 'elasticsearch':
        manage_repo  => true,
        repo_version => '2.2',
        require      => Class['java']
    }

    elasticsearch::instance { 'es-01':
        require => Package['elasticsearch'],
    }

}
```

The above code errors with:

> Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Rehan::Elasticsearch] is already declared; cannot redeclare at..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Puppet 3 (even with the future parser!), you need to use:

```
class { '::elasticsearch':
    manage_repo  => true,
    repo_version => '2.2',
    require      => Class['java']
}
```

In Puppet 4, the resolution rules for types, classes and variables changed (it doens't try to resolve them contextually), so your code is valid.

Comment: I was hoping to use a namespace somehow, like `elasticsearch::elasticsearch`.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Ah I misunderstood the question. I guess you're using Puppet 3.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed I changed the answer.